# Replace $ with a Function using Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having a SQL query with a following part...

> BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321'

In this I want to replace the $ with a PL/SQL function which i defined already, and I need the output to be

> BRANCH='Chennai' AND decode_acc_no(ACCOUNT_NO)='12312321'

What will be the regular expression do I need to use with the String to get the required output??..

Comment: So, you're basically looking for `s/\$([A-Za-z0-9_])/decode_acc_no(\1)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
String str = "BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321'";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("^(.+?)\\$([A-Z_]+)(.*)$", "$1decode_acc_no($2)$3");
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Prints:

> BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321'
>
> BRANCH='Chennai' AND decode_acc_no(ACCOUNT_NO)='12312321'

EDIT: As per your comment, no, this will only match the structure you gave in your question. If you want more flexibility, you can use this: `\\$(A-Z_]+)`

```
String str = "BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321' OR $BENIFICIARY_ACC_NO='2323434'"
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\$([A-Z_]+)", "decode_acc_no($1)");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Prints out the following:

> BRANCH='Chennai' AND decode_acc_no(ACCOUNT_NO)='12312321' OR decode_acc_no(BENIFICIARY_ACC_NO)='2323434'

Comment: Will this work for multiple replacement also?? like for "BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321' OR $BENIFICIARY_ACC_NO='2323434'"

Comment: @ArunDavid: No it does not. However, I have updated the answer. Now it should replace any element preceeded by a `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
query.replace("\\$([A-Za-z0-9_]*)", "decode_acc_no($1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be

*String original = "BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321'";
        System.out.println(original.replace("' AND $ACCOUNT_NO", "' AND decode_acc_no(ACCOUNT_NO)"));*

You can also use a regex s/\$([A-Za-z_]*)/decode_acc_no(\1)/g

Answer (score 0):

```
String in = "BRANCH='Chennai' AND $ACCOUNT_NO='12312321'";
String result = in.replaceAll("\\$([^=]+)", "decode_acc_no($1)");
```

**Output:**

> BRANCH='Chennai' AND decode_acc_no(ACCOUNT_NO)='12312321'

The regex `\\$([^=]+)` searches for a `$` character and matches then everything that is not a `=`. This is stored in the first capturing group. The content of that capturing group is reused in the replacement string by using `$1`.

[What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)
<sub>Disclaimer: My own blog post</sub>